# Symfony3 Impossible to access attributes

Tags: php, orm, relational-database, symfony-3.1

I am having trouble with understanding this error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("naam") on a integer variable ("0") in cursusmoment/index.html.twig at line 22.

Here is mij twig template:

```
{% for cursusMoment in cursusMoments %}
<tr>
  <td><a href="{{ path('cursusmoment_show', { 'id': cursusMoment.id }) }}">{{ cursusMoment.id }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ cursusMoment.cursus.naam }}</td>
  <td>{% if cursusMoment.startDate %}{{ cursusMoment.startDate|date('d-m-y') }}{% endif %}</td>
  <td>{% if cursusMoment.endDate %}{{ cursusMoment.endDate|date('d-m-y') }}{% endif %}</td>
  <td>{{ cursusMoment.cursusSubscriptions }}</td>
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('cursusmoment_show', { 'id': cursusMoment.id }) }}">Tonen</a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('cursusmoment_edit', { 'id': cursusMoment.id }) }}">Aanpassen</a>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

CursusMoment Entity

namespace CursusBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * CursusMoment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cursus_moment")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CursusBundle\Repository\CursusMomentRepository")
 */
class CursusMoment
{
    /**

     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date")
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_date", type="date")
     */
    private $endDate;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cursus", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cursus", inversedBy="cursusMoments")
     */
    private $cursus;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cursusSubscriptions", type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CursusSubscription", mappedBy="cursusMoment", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $cursusSubscriptions;

    /**
     * CursusMoment constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cursusSubscriptions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Set cursus
     *
     * @param integer $cursus
     *
     * @return CursusMoment
     */
    public function setCursus($cursus)
    {
        $this->cursus = $cursus;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: What is `naam` in your app?

Comment: @DanCostinel naam is is the name of the course(cursus). As you can see i am working with associations.

Comment: I can see that, but this means the `naam` is a column in a db table, which does exists in an Entity class as a property? And moreover, that Entity class is in a relationship with `CursusMoment` Entity class? If these assumptions are true, then this means you want to create a join between the two Entities? If the answer for this last question is yes, then have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html).

Comment: Yes you are right i've the docs so it should be something like /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cursus", type="integer")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cursus", inversedBy="cursusMoments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="cursus_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $cursus; is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I'm very tired right now, so I can't figure out your code. But anyways, [here's](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/many-to-one-relation) an example of how you should deal with this stuff. Then, the way you try to access the data (`{{ cursusMoment.cursus.naam }}`) is wrong. Read through the KNP's tutorial to see how to fix your error.

Comment: OK thx for trying!